# Min-Max principle - Subspaces over $H_0^1$

Tags: spectral-theory

I am trying to understand what is going on (in using the Minimax Principle; [Weyl's law](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/weyl_law.pdf))  in the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem

> $$\left\{ \begin{aligned}
>  -u''(x)&=\lambda u(x)\quad 0<x<\pi\\ u(0)&=0\\ u(\pi)&=0. \end{aligned} \right.$$

I think I might use the fact that the set of eigenfunctions $\{\sin k x\}_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ is complete in $L^2((0,\pi))$

> **Lemma.** *(Minimax Principle, Version 2)* $$\lambda_n = \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(H_0^1)} \{ \sup_{u \in X} \rho(u) \}$$ where
>   $\Phi_n(H_0^1)=\{n-\text{dimensional linear subspace } X \subset H_0^1 \}$.

**Precision :** $\rho(u)$ is the Rayleigh quotient

Clearly, I know that the $1$ and $2$-dimensional linear subspaces $X \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ are the lines and planes in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ but how could we interpret, for instance, a $2$-dimensional linear subspace $X \in \Phi_n(H_0^1)$ (Complete answer would be appreciated)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: here you are not considering the subspace of $L^2([0,\pi])$ generated by the $\{\sin(kx)\}$, not the  $H^1_0([0,\pi])$ norm. A plane is still defined by two orthogonal unit vectors. The unit vectors are of the form $w_1 = \sum_k a_k \sqrt{2}\sin(kx)$ with $\|w_k\|_{L^2([0,\pi])}^2 = \sum_k a_k^2= 1$, and another one $w_2 = \sum_k b_k \sqrt{2}\sin(kx)$ is orthogonal if $\langle w_1,w_2 \rangle_{L^2([0,\pi])} = \sum_k a_k b_k = 0$

Comment: so for a subspace $X$, and $u \in X$, can you compute $\rho(u)$ ?

Comment: show me $ {}{}{}{}       $

Comment: what about $\max_{u \in X} \rho(u)$ and $\min_{u \in X}  \rho(u)$  ?